# visual studio и синтаксис CUDA

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, cuda

Изучаю CUDA.

Поставил Toolkit на VS 2015 community. Всё вроде как встало, шаблон добавился сам, файл с расширением .cu создаётся, примеры кода компилируются и правильно работают.

Но писать неудобно - автодополнения для функций и констант из CUDA нет совсем. Например, под пунктом 1 я полностью ввел команду cudaMalloc, но среда ее не понимает и не выдает справку до тех пор, пока я не введу все параметры.

Кроме того, среда не понимает синтаксис некоторых вещей, например, вызова ядра <<<>>> - очень уж уродливо форматирует. Я всё это отметил на прикрепленной картинке.

Вопрос: это всё так должно быть, или я что-то делаю не так?

[image: Неудобства при написании кода]